# Advent Of Code 2021: Day 3 Part 1 | characters not added to variable in PYTHON

Tags: python, list, file, for-loop, variables

This is my code and my output doesn't even look like its right, I think the 0 and 1 aren't being concatenated to the variables.

```
#Day 3 Part 1
one_count = 0
zero_count = 0

gamma = ""
espilon = ""

with open('input3.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
    nums = [str(num) for num in data.splitlines()]

nums = [list(i) for i in nums]
#print(nums)

for j in range(0, 12):

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        if "1" in nums[i][j]:
            one_count += 1

        elif "0" in nums[i][j]:
            zero_count += 1
        

if zero_count > one_count:
    gamma += "0"
    espilon += "1"

    zero_count = 0
    one_count = 0

elif one_count > zero_count:
    gamma += "1"
    espilon += "0"

    zero_count = 0
    one_count = 0

print(gamma)
print(espilon)
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

I don't think I can add the 1,000 line txt file but you can visit the advent of code 2021 website yourself and check out day 3 part 1's input.

[Advent of code Day 3](https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/3)

Comment: **you** may share the input, not every stackoverlow user that could help you

Comment: @azro https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/3/input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you need ot apply the logic (count zeros and ones) for **each** bit position (or each column), not just once as your code does

The easiest is to iterate on the columns, use `zip` to transpose from the rows, then for each find the most and lest common (one is the opposite of the other)

```
puzzle = """00100\n11110\n10110\n10111\n10101\n01111\n00111\n11100\n10000\n11001\n00010\n01010"""

rows = puzzle.splitlines()  # ['00100', '11110', '10110', ..
cols = list(zip(*rows))  # [('0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0'), ...
gamma = ""  # most common
epsilon = ""  # least common

for col in cols:
    if col.count('1') > col.count('0'):  # most common is 1
        gamma += '1'
        epsilon += '0'
    else:  # most common is 0
        gamma += '0'
        epsilon += '1'

gamma = int(gamma, 2)
epsilon = int(epsilon, 2)
power = gamma * epsilon

print(f"{gamma=} {epsilon=} {power=}")  # gamma=22 epsilon=9 power=198
```

---

Binary math could be used too

```
gamma = 0
epsilon = 0
l = len(cols)
for idx, col in enumerate(cols):
    if col.count('1') > col.count('0'):
        gamma += 2 ** (l - idx - 1)
    else:
        epsilon += 2 ** (l - idx - 1)
power = gamma * epsilon
```

Comment: what does int(gamma, 2) do? like the ",2" part

Comment: @LocalDogeCoder convert with base 2, not base 10